# How to integrate sonarqube with Azure active directory?

Tags: sonarqube, openid, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I tried using sonarqube's openid plugin. But it does not work with google accounts as google has migrated to openid connect and has stopped support  for openid.

Please suggest ways as how to can I integrate with Azure AD as there are no plugins provided in sonarqube update center for openid connect and saml.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick sweep on the Sonarqube site, the product does not appear to support any protocol that would be compatible with Azure AD today. The only page I found was http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Security - and it does not list any of the protocols that could be used with Azure AD (OpenID Connect, SAML, WS-Federation)

Answer (score 0):

here it is.

- Create an app on azure portal and follow steps as listed below
- worked for me
  https://github.com/hkamel/sonar-auth-aad/wiki/Setup

also

https://www.emtec.digital/think-hub/blogs/sonarqube-integration-azure-active-directory/